# Build solution in Visual studio

Tags: c

Hi was trying to enter the following code into visual studio and when i click build solutions, there were 98 errors.. e.g. syntax error..

Can anyone advise if i've done it incorrectly ? The steps i've taken were:

- open visual studio
- create new proj
- empty proj
- Source file -- right click -- new item -- rename as test.c instead of .cpp
- copy code below and build solution

However, i realised when i changed the name from test.c to helloworld.c then it worked. Any idea why ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: My test project has test.c and test.cpp in it with no issues. Without knowing any of the errors it's hard to guess what was going on. If you rename the file back to test.c do the errors return?

Comment: i've attached a screenshot of the errors in my post..

Comment: @Noobiee What is the *first* error, if you look in the Output window (not the Error List window)?

Comment: So, you said that you created a new project and added one file to it and got errors. Your screenshot shows a project with 3 files in it, none with the name "test.c". Which is it? What's in the two files we can't see? Looks like probably `#include <cstdlib>` at least which is a C++ header so it makes perfect sense it doesn't work when included in a C file.

Comment: Renaming the file isn't enough - you also need to change the files in the project in the little window on the right to have the right filenames.  Why is it complaining about errors in the cstdlib header when you haven't included that?  Or is it included in one of the other two files in the project?  Why do you have three files in the project - they don't all contain a main function do they?

Comment: hmm not sure where is the output window... could you point me to it ? cos it doesnt run so there wasnt any pop up window..

Comment: im actually doing a c program no a c++.. sld i still put it as #include <cstdlib> ?

Comment: may i know how should the files be named ? cos i thought we could give it any name ? the 3 files inside are juz different codes that i wanted to create and run with the first being hello world... sorry have never really done coding before so pls pardon n bear with me...even if i set up a new project and just copy the hello world as seen in my post, there are still errors..

Comment: @Noobiee The Output windows can be opened from the menu View / Output.

Comment: `#include <cstdlib>` is a C++ header. The C header is `#include <stdlib.h>` Generally the headers without extensions are for C++. These may help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header